# How can I create 4096 sectors on an MBR drive to match the configuration of older drives in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, fdisk

Few years ago I bought 2 drives that came pre-formatted with 4096 byte sector and MBR partition table.

Now I bought 3rd drive but as it's more recent revision it came preformatted to GPT. When I'm trying to create MBR partition it of course fails because `fdisk` by default creates `512` bytes sector MBR and drive is 6TB.

How can I create 4096 sectors on an MBR drive to match the configuration of older drives in Linux?

Currently `fdisk` shows:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (maximum/optimal): 4096 / 4096 bytes
```

On old disks it shows:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (maximum/optimal): 4096 / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: How do you connect the disks? Is any USB bridge/enclosure involved?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need to use MBR, though?

Comment: @grawity yes - I already have MBR on the other 2 drives and it's RAID array. I'm trying to expand RAID array with this third drive so _I think_ they should have more or less the same specification. Plus I don't see any reason why should I use some compatibility layer of 512 byte sectors if native for drive is 4096.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski all drives are connected via the same USB 3.0 HUB. But I also tried to connect without hub with the same result. All drives are  WD Elements 5TB, 5TB and 6TB.

Comment: The man page for my version of the `fdisk` program ("fdisk from util-linux 2.32") says that it is "able to optimize the disk layout for a 4K-sector size" and also sports a `-b sectorsize` option for overriding the default. Have you tried that?

Comment: @JohanMyréen "optimizing disk layout" means that partitions are aligned to 4096 sector size but it doesn't imply actual usage of 4096 sectors. Yes I tried `-b 4096` but then it shows that my disk is 800GB or something like this.

Comment: @Lapsio Ok, good to know that fdisk's 4k support is buggy. Fdisk is aware of the larger sector size, but still thinks they are 512 byte sectors? One more nail in the coffin for MBR partition table, and a win for GPT.

Comment: "2 drive RAID array"  Depending on how they are RAID the RAID controller usually put a custom format on the hard drive.  Thus erasing whatever you place there.  It might operate differently with a software based RAID.  For a hardware RAID you initialize the disk, which wipes out whatever you have done.

Comment: @cybernard yeah I'm using btrfs raid. Actually I just noticed that 2 original drives are not the same size either, they differ in few mb and it's still non-issue for btrfs. I already started rebalancing from raid1 to raid5 but had to cancel it in the middle so for now my array is 80% raid5 and 20% raid1 but for btrfs it's also fine situation xD. I'll finish rebalancing it some day.